# Uniqueness of generators and relations

Tags: group-theory

Let $S$ be a set and let $R \subset (S \cup S^{-1})^*$, where $(S \cup S^{-1})^*$ is the set of words.

1. Show that the group $\langle S|R \rangle$ generated by $S$ with the relations $R$ together with the canonical map $\pi : S \rightarrow F(S)/\langle \langle R\rangle \rangle = \langle S|R \rangle$ has the following universal property : For every group $H$ and every map $\phi : S \rightarrow H$ satisfying  $\forall_{r\in R} \phi^*(r) = e$, there is exactly one group homomorphism $\bar\phi : \langle S|R \rangle \rightarrow H$ with $\bar\phi \circ \pi = \phi$; here , $\phi^* : (S \cup S^{-1})^* \rightarrow H$ is defined inductively by $\phi^*(\epsilon) = e$ and $\forall_{s\in S}\forall_{x\in (S\cup S^{-1})^*} \phi^*(sx) = \phi (s).\phi^*(x)$ and $\forall_{s\in S}\forall_{x\in (S\cup S^{-1})^*} \phi^*(s^{-1}x) = (\phi (s))^{-1}.\phi^*(x)$.
2. Prove that up to canonical isomorphism, there is exactly one group that has this universal property.

Here, $\langle\langle R \rangle \rangle$ denotes the normal closure.

In the above problem, I have been able to solve the first part and it is quite obvious. However, I do not know how to go about the second part. I am not able to understand what the second part wants me to prove.

Comment: This is standard for universal properties. If $G$ and $u\colon S\to G$ have the same universal property, use the universal property of $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ to define a map from $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ to $G$ making a certain triangle commute, use the universal property of $G$ to get a map $G\to \langle S\mid R\rangle$ making the corresponding triangle commute, then show that the compositions have the desired property, as does the identity maps and use the uniqueness of the universal property to conclude the two maps are inverses of each other.

Comment: Actually, you need to add that the map $\pi$ has the property that $\pi^*(r)=e$ for all $r\in R$, and that is part of the universal property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the standard argument to show that objects with certain universal properties are unique up to unique isomorphism...

Note that part of the universal property of $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ and $\pi$ are that $\pi^*(r)=e$ for all $r\in R$.

Assume that $G$ and $p\colon S\to G$ have the corresponding universal property. That is:

> $p^*(r)=e$ for all $r\in R$, and for every group $H$ and every map $\phi\colon S\to H$ satisfying $\phi^*(r)=e$ for every $r\in R$, there is a unique group homomorphism $\overline{\phi}\colon G\to H$ such that $\overline{\phi}\circ p=\phi$.

Now, because $\pi\colon S\to \langle S\mid R\rangle$ is such that $\pi^*(r)=e$ for all $r\in R$, there is a unique group homomorphism $\overline{\pi}\colon G\to\langle S\mid R\rangle$ such that $\overline{\pi}\circ p =\pi$.

And because $p$ has the property that for every $r\in R$ we have $p^*(r)=e$, then there exists a unique morphism $\overline{p}\colon \langle S\mid R\rangle \to G$ such that $\overline{p}\circ\pi = p$, by the universal property of $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ and $\pi$.

Now consider $\pi$; there is a unique map $f\colon \langle S\mid R\rangle\to\langle S\mid R\rangle$ such that $f\circ\pi = \pi$; and clearly $f=\mathrm{id}_{\langle S\mid R\rangle}$ is such a map, so that is the unique map. Symmetrically, considering $p$ we know there is a unique map $g\colon G\to G$ such that $g\circ p = p$, and $g=\mathrm{id}_G$ is clearly such a map, hence it is the only such map by the uniqueness clause.

But now note that we have that
$$\pi = \overline{\pi}\circ p = \overline{\pi}\circ(\overline{p}\circ \pi) = (\overline{\pi}\circ \overline{p})\circ\pi.$$
By the uniqueness clause of the universal property, as we saw above, that means that $\overline{\pi}\circ\overline{p} = \mathrm{id}_{\langle S\mid R\rangle}$. Symmetrically,
$$p = \overline{p}\circ\pi = \overline{p}\circ \overline{\pi}\circ{p},$$
so by the uniqueness clause we have $\overline{p}\circ\overline{\pi} = \mathrm{id}_G$.

Thus, $\overline{\pi}$ and $\overline{p}$ are inverses of each other, hence isomorphisms, and their uniqueness gives their canonicity relative to $\pi$.